# foundation 6, empty columns

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I wanted my columns look like this:

```
| CONTENT | CONTENT | CONTENT | CONTENT | EMPTY | EMPTY |
```

so I created it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

But the last column is pulled right:

```
| CONTENT | CONTENT | CONTENT | EMPTY | EMPTY | CONTENT |
```

So to avoid it should I add those two additional empty columns to the `row` div? It works with those additional empty divs, but I don't really like idea of adding empty divs. Even adding one empty div prevents floating right.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add class 'end' to the last column

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="columns medium-4 large-2 end">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```